Can a 36" shelf be supported by two brackets spaced 32" apart?
I am installing 36" wide, 24" deep metal wire shelves in a garage closet. There will be 4 shelves installed on top of each other. Specifically, I am installing these Fleximount shelves in this area:

Each self comes with two support brackets that get attached to studs with 3 lag bolts each:

In an ideal world, for 16" spaced studs the brackets would be attached to studs 10" from each side of the shelf. However, the framing of this closet forces me to mount the brackets 2" from each end of the shelf. The top down view would look like:

I am not sure if this will provide adequate support for the shelf. There is the middle stud I can attach a third bracket to, but I would have to acquire more brackets to do so. My questions are

Will installing the two provided brackets in this configuration support the shelf without failing?
If not, would a 20" L-bracket added to the middle stud be sufficient?


I'm voting to close as opinion-based--it's entirely a matter of sag tolerance. It's not going to collapse if it's mounted properly, but it may have a slight belly if you load it down. That said, I would just try it with your load. No sense buying extra hardware if you won't need it. It's a simple thing to add another bracket later.

If you want to put stuff on the shelves, go with a middle bracket.
I would also tie/mount the shelve to the bracket somehow.  To keep it from tipping.
Zip-ties, wire, get fancy with small bolts to hold something to keep the shelve down.

I have never heard someone say 'I wish I had put this shelf up with fewer brackets'. More is very much better.

Not really. More brackets means less open space under the shelf and more expense and effort. If it's not needed, it's not needed. Most of my garage shelves are supported on 32" intervals.

I am hesitant to put another bracket because I want to store my 24" wide, 14" tall toolbox on one shelf. If I add another bracket, the next shelf would need to be higher to account for the added height of the bracket

@Luke   It will depend on the weight added to the shelf, but some shelf brackets take very little room, not as deep as the ones in the picture.
